# Puppeteer custom header footer for PDF render

Tags: pdf-generation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am working on rendering a PDF of a site. I want different headers and footers for the first page and different for the rest of the pages. Is there any way to do this?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
 var t = Date.now();
 console.log('Current time ' + t + ' msec'); 

 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', ignoreHTTPSErrors:true, headless:true, devtools:false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});

await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({'Report-Print-Preview-Mode':'true'});
await page.goto('https://localhost', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
await page.type('#username', 'scott');
await page.type('#password', 'tiger');  
await page.click('[id="login_button"]');

await page.waitForSelector('[id="new_page_table_id"]');
await page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()));

// page.pdf() is currently supported only in headless mode.
// @see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753118

await page.pdf({
path: 'report.pdf',
displayHeaderFooter: true,
headerTemplate: '<span style="font-size: 30px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: black; color:black; margin: 20px;">Header</span>', 
footerTemplate: '<span style="font-size: 30px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: black; color:black; margin: 20px;">Footer</span>',
printBackground: true,
format: 'A4',
margin:{top:'2cm',right:'2cm',bottom:'2cm',left:'2cm'}
});

await browser.close();

t = Date.now() - t;
console.log('Execution time ' + t + ' msec');
})();
```

How can I achieve it? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "out of box" puppeteer implementation of the feature you are requesting.

In the same time there are a couple of ways as work around described at "[Ability to prevent header/footer on certain pages](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2089)". The first suggestion is to convert multiple times with different range and use of different header/footer combos; after merge resulting buffers with something like https://github.com/astefanutti/decktape. And another, hacky solution by using `@page:first` CSS style.