# Trying to hide first footer/header on PDF generated with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer

Im new using nodejs functions and also puppeteer. Previously I was using wkhtmltopdf but currently its options are very poor.

So, my idea was generating a pdf from a html with a first cover page (an image with full A4 width/height ), since the footer is generated from the index.js, theres no way to hide it on the FIRST page of the PDF.

```
//Imports
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
//Open browser
async function startBrowser() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args:['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    return {browser, page};
}
//Close browser
async function closeBrowser(browser) {
    return browser.close();
}
//Html to pdf
async function html2pdf(url) {
    const {browser, page} = await startBrowser();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.emulateMedia('screen');
    //Options
    await page.pdf({
        printBackground: true,
        path: 'result.pdf',
        displayHeaderFooter: true,
        footerTemplate: '<div style="width:100%;text-align:right;position:relative;top:10px;right:10px;"><img width="60px" src="data:data:image/..."'
        margin : {top: '0px',right: '0px',bottom: '40px',left: '0px' },
        scale: 1,
        landscape: false,
        format: 'A4',
        pageRanges: ""
    });
}
//Exec
(async () => {
    await html2pdf('file:///loc/node_pdfs/givenhtml.html');
    process.exit(1);
})();
```

My question is, is there any way to locate the first footer and hide it from the index fuction?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try this https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2089#issuecomment-379934407

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [Puppeteer custom header footer for PDF render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404672/puppeteer-custom-header-footer-for-pdf-render/52486783#52486783)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are currently multiple bugs (see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14008461/5627599) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22596570/5627599)) that make it impossible to get this working.

This is currently only possible for headers using this trick (taken from this [github comment](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2089#issuecomment-379934407)):

```js
await page.addStyleTag({
    content: `
        body { margin-top: 1cm; }
        @page:first { margin-top: 0; }
    `,
});
```

This will basically hide the margin on the first page, but will not work when using a bottom margin (as also noted [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2089#issuecomment-405437229)).

### Possible Solution

The solution I recommend is to create two PDFs, one with only the first page and no margins, and another one with the remaining pages and a margin:

```js
await page.pdf({
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
    pageRanges: '1',
    path: 'page1.pdf',
});

await page.pdf({
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    footerTemplate: '<div style="font-size:5mm;">Your footer text</div>',
    margin: {
        bottom: '10mm'
    },
    pageRanges: '2-', // start this PDF at page 2
    path: 'remaining-pages.pdf',
});
```

Depending on how often you need to perform the task you could either manually merge the PDFs or automate it using a tool like [easy-pdf-merge](https://github.com/karuppiah7890/easy-pdf-merge) (I have not used this one myself).

Comment: Well, looks like manipulating margin bottom is not possible, so second solution is Ok for me since the first page will be static. Thanks Thomas!

Comment: I'm using the second solution and it is giving me an error. Protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Page range syntax error

await page.pdf({ format: 'A3', printBackground: true, pageRanges: '2-' })

In my case, I needed to show the header and footer on the first page only not on the others. @Thomas Dondorf

Comment: oh I got it to issue was because my pdf page length was only 1 but how it is possible to determine the pdf page counts at runtime?

Answer (score 4):

small hint: `easy-pdf-merge` an `pdf-merge` have some "system-tools-dependencies"
I prefer `pdf-lib`, a plain js tool where you can use Buffers and Typescript support

My Typescript:

```js
import {PDFDocument} from 'pdf-lib'
...

const options: PDFOptions = {
    format: 'A4',
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    footerTemplate: footerTemplate,
    margin: {
        top: '20mm',
        bottom: '20mm',
    },
}
const page1: Buffer = await page.pdf({
    ...options,
    headerTemplate: '<div><!-- no header hack --></div>',
    pageRanges: '1',
})
const page2: Buffer = await page.pdf({
    ...options,
    headerTemplate: headerTemplate,
    pageRanges: '2-',
})

const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create()

const coverDoc = await PDFDocument.load(page1)
const [coverPage] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(coverDoc, [0])
pdfDoc.addPage(coverPage)

const mainDoc = await PDFDocument.load(page2)
for (let i = 0; i < mainDoc.getPageCount(); i++) {
    const [aMainPage] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(mainDoc, [i])
    pdfDoc.addPage(aMainPage)
}

const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()

// Buffer for https response in my case
return Buffer.from(pdfBytes)
...
```