# Render header on all pages in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

When I set `displayHeaderFooter` to `true`, the header will not render. It works only when I set margin to `@page` in CSS, but then the page height is increased by margin value and page content is rendered outside of the page.

Is there a solution for the headline to appear on every page without bugs ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the margin of the content by using the `margin` option of [`page.pdf`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions). By default the margin is `0` for all sides, therefore if you set a header without a margin it will be hidden behind the content of the page.

The margin you set via this option, will not increase the height of the page. If possible, I would recommend to not use the `@page` rules from CSS, as there are multiple known bugs (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55480268/5627599) for more information).

#### Code sample

Here is an minimal example which sets a header for all pages and sets the margin to `20mm` to make it visible:

```js
await page.pdf({
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    headerTemplate: '<div style="font-size:5mm;">Your header text</div>',
    margin: {
        top: '20mm'
    },
    path: 'example.pdf'
});
```