# @Page query - hiding header in @page:first seems to misplace all trailing footers (using Puppeteer)

Tags: css, node.js, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer in Node to turn my React App into pdf. I want to have a frontpage (an image covering the entire page), so I want to hide the footer/header there. There are no available options to achieve this in Puppeteer, so I gave @page queries in css priority over Puppeteer sizes etc.

We start off with this css:

```
@page {
  size: 210mm 297mm;
}
```

This will show the header (template is in puppeteer) on every page except the first page. My footer is nowhere to be seen, except on the last page. So I change the css to this:

```
@page {
  size: 210mm, 297mm;
  margin-bottom: 16mm;
}
```

This will now show the footer on the first and last page, but nowhere inbetween. The header is still like I want it (hidden on the first page, visible on every other page).

For some reason, if I up the margin-bottom to 48mm, the footer will become visible on every page. On the first page, it will actually shove the content up 48mm like expected, and put the footer in there. On other pages, it acts like the equivalent of a 16mm margin. I think this is because for some reason the page's margin and the page itself starts 32mm below the actual visible page. This does not work like this for the first and last page.

However, if I define a margin-top with an absolute value, so the header is visible on every single page, the footer also shows up correctly on every single page. So it seems like me hiding the header on the first page somehow misplaces all the footers except the first and last.

If I now add this css:

```
@page:first {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Then the footer on the first page disappears (intended), but every other footer, except for the last one, also disappears. I think this might be because hiding the footer on the first page will move the other footers even more out of place. So I tested by incrementing 10mm each time, and testing the range 0mm - 300m margin-bottom, to no avail.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: AFAIK, this is still [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55480268/5627599) due to multiple bugs in Chromium.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf Yeah. I also flagged my post as duplicate now. A few hours after I posted this I ended up setting up easy-pdf-merge. I haven't installed java, which it needs as a dependency, so I don't know if it's going to work yet. We'll see.

Comment: Wish you the best, I remember trying to get this to work myself some while back ago and gave up at one point. Maybe one day, they'll fix the CSS/page bugs... :)